# Are arrays “more abstract” than stacks or queues?

Tags: arrays, stacks, queues, abstract-data-types

It seems to me that an array can be used as a stack or a queue and for various other things.

In my mind this makes an array a higher order abstraction compared to those other two.

Is this an acceptable argument or are there other preferred ways to determine order of abstraction that would invert my line of thought?

Comment: I don’t know how to understand your terms, but in memory, at a natural level, there are only arrays. From them, more abstract structures are created - stacks, lists, etc. Perhaps someone can give an example of a hardware based stack.

Comment: I think you've understood the point as well as I did :) Here's a link to a situation where one person suggested that the term stack was a more abstract way of referring to an array and its access pattern: https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/148587/147393 I think that use of 'more abstract' is somewhat casual unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @JohnVandivier, I think you're conflating different possible senses of the word "abstract", with some "higher order" thrown in for more confusion. Arrays (in the sense of a series of fixed-length elements) are basic in computing, and they are general in the sense that all other things are created from them.

Comment: How would you define "higher order abstraction" and "more abstract"?  That sounds like a matter of interpretation or opinion to me...

Comment: If a is a generalization of b it is a higher-order abstraction; if b meets the criteria of a and adds additional opinions or assumptions it is lower order. a matter of interpretation perhaps but this is how developers routinely talk